# joining tables on multiple matched values

Tags: mysql, join

Given table1 with fields **person1_id, person2_id and person3_id**

and table 2 with fields **fname, lname, id**, I want to return the names from table2 for person1_id, person2_id, and person3_id, hopefully in one query.

I understand how to do a join to retrieve one name, but not multiple names.

Thanks

Comment: Please post a sample of rows from each table together with a sample of what you expect the query output to be. Remember that a join condition is merely a boolean, so often it is just a matter of logical AND or OR like `ON person1_id =t2.id OR person2_id = t2.id OR...`

Comment: yes, post some sample rows in each table and the sample of the output you expect.

Comment: Sorry to be so thick.  Do I post this under Add A Comment?  I fear that the rows are so long that they will just be a jumble.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple join for 1 table.
Please try this, and let me know if this could solved your issue.

```
select e.*,
students1.fname, students1.lname,
students2.fname, students2.lname,
students3.fname, students3.lname
from events as e
left join students as students1 on students1.stu_id1 = e.stu_id
left join students as students2 on students2.stu_id2 = e.stu_id
left join students as students3 on students3.stu_id3 = e.stu_id
```

Comment: Thank you RubahMalam,  unfortunately I can not get this to work.

The actual tables are

students with fields of fname, lname and stu_id

and

events with fields of date, day, stu_id1, stu_id2, and stu_id3

My goal is to return one row with all of the fields in events and the actual names that go with stu_id1, stu_id2, and stu_id3

Regards,
Dave

Comment: @DaveDavis Please see my edits with your actual tables.

Comment: Thank you so very much.  I had to change  the
on students1.stu_id1 = e.stu_id
to
on students1.stu_id1 = e.stu_id1, etc, but now it works brilliantly

Answer (score 0):

I think help you this sql query...

```
SELECT table2.fname, table2.lname, table2.id
FROM table2
FULL JOIN table1
ON table2.id=table1.person1_id OR table2.id=table1.person2_id OR table2.id=table1.person3_id ORDER BY table2.id;
```

Comment: Thank you.  This returns multiple rows.  I am looking for a query to return one row that includes all of the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Based on above answer

```
SELECT table2.fname, table2.lname, table2.id
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1
ON 
(table2.id=table1.person1_id OR table2.id=table1.person2_id OR table2.id=table1.person3_id)
 ORDER BY table2.id;
```